# Showing Related Content in other Content in Drupal 7

Tags: module, drupal-7

I am building a website with recipes in Drupal 7. I also have cooking tips on the website and for some of the recipes I want to show related cooking tips on the page of the recipe.

I have two content types, one for the recipes and one for the cooking tips.

What would you consider the best module for this? I already tried the References Module but this only worked in the View with an overview of all recipes, not on the page of a specific recipe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be http://drupal.org/project/Relation ?